# Missing Photos from Timeline Photos album

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to get all the photos of a user `graphPath: me/albums` and find something weird with Timeline Photos album.

Photos exist in Timeline album on Facebook, but not returned from API call `graphPath/{timeline_photos_album_id}/photos`, or they are returned with lower number of photos.

What is the problem?

**Logs:**

Calling for albums `graphPath: me/albums`:

```
.....
{
     "can_upload" = 0;
      count = 3; !!!!!!!!!!!
      "created_time" = "2013-06-18T10:43:27+0000";
      description = cool;
      from = {
                id = 100006100533891;
                name = "Mike Mike";
            };
      id = 1387760311437307;
      link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php? 
          fbid=1387760311437307&id=100006100533891&aid=1073741829";
      name = "Timeline Photos";
      privacy = everyone;
      type = wall;
      "updated_time" = "2013-06-18T10:47:53+0000”;
 },
 .....
```

Calling for album photos `graphPath/{timeline_photos_album_id}/photos`:

```
{
    data =     (
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you checked the permissions and visibility status of each wall posts? If some are restricted to very narrow groups, it may not show in the photo's list.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Good idea! I think permission could be one of the reasons! thank you for highlighting. would give a try :P

Comment: I think the response for graphPath/{timeline_photos_album_id}/photos cannot be correct as it's not a valid JSON...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately ["it is not a bug, it is by design"](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228835560621977).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following (with "user_photos" permission) and it works:

Fetch the album photo count for my user:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=id,count&access_token={access_token}
```

The result is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{album_id}", 
      "count": 161, 
      "created_time": "2010-11-05T15:41:42+0000"
    }, 
    ....
}
```

Then query for the photos of this album:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{album_id}/photos?fields=id&limit=500&access_token={access_token}
```

The result is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{photo_id1}", 
      "created_time": "2013-12-29T09:59:52+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "{photo_id2}", 
      "created_time": "2013-12-17T10:40:26+0000"
    },
    ...
}
```

I count the correct number of 161 ids in the result. So everything seems to work fine.

You can also test this via FQL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+pid+from+photo+where+album_object_id+=+{album_id}+limit+1000&access_token={access_token}
```

Answer (score 1):

there have been changes in the FB API recently, did you try to add the fields you want to get back in the result from the API? In the past, API always returned "standard fields", newest you always have to provide a list of fields of what you want to have back in the result such as `....fields=name,id...`

Comment: The fields are not of my concern. I just want to receive the same number of photos, as there was stated in albom count from me/albums request

Comment: And what do you expect? For fifteen photos fifteen empty records?

Comment: If you are not going to provide me with 15 photos, don't state that you will

Comment: look at @Tobi's answer, his approach is confirming what I said.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `user_photos` permission in the Access Token. The end point:
`/{timeline_photos_album_id}/photos` is working perfectly fine for me when I tried it using the Graph API Explorer to retrieve photos from my Timeline photos album. And, I don't think that it is necessary to provide the fields.

I'll suggest you should try the same using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=1387760311437307/photos). Just press the **Get Access Token** button on the top right and check the `user_photos` permission to test your request.

---

In case you are getting lesser results, you can try your query using pagination options `limit` and `offset`. This sometimes returns more results as compare to normal(nothing about this on docs, just my personal experience). Something like:

```
{timeline_photo_album_id}/photos?limit=500&offset=0
```

But again, as you pointed out, there are strange things going on with the API. Take a look at [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/). This article refers to it as an expected behavior of the API!

Comment: Nope. I tried retrieved my photos and had the same problem. The count returned 83 and I received 53. It happens in the Graph API Explorer too. Thanks for the link though

Comment: Hi! I've updated my answer. You can take a look at it. But I guess you're right. Facebook API sucks sometimes. It's behavior is quite unexpected.